# IE won't render in IE8 Document Mode

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a website that renders well in IE8+, however my clients have their IE8 browsers set to `Document Mode: IE7 Standards` and they think the website is broken when it is not.

Everywhere I've read seem to imply that the answer to this problem is to simply add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` immedately after the `<head>` tag.  However, when I try to test this by setting `Document Mode: IE7 Standards` via the IE F12 developer tools, it won't render into the IE8 Document Mode.

Steps I'm using to test this:

1. In IE, open up http://johngoosey.com
2. What you should see:  50%/50% vertical split screen with navigation on the left and content on the right.
3. Open up Developer Tools via F12
4. Set Document Mode to IE7 standards
5. The 50%/50% split stacks with the navigation on the top left and the content on the bottom right.

If you do a view source, you'll see that I have the meta tag there.  I've tried all combinations of different meta content values (ie: IE=edge, IE=8, IE=EmulateIE8) with no luck.  Any and all advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that IE7's box model is screwing things up.

As an example, change the left padding on `.columns.colLeft` to 0, and the right padding in `.columns.colRight` to 0.

One way you could deal with this is via a conditional class like:

```
.ie8compat .columns.colLeft {
    padding-right:0;
}

.ie8compat .columns.colRight {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

Comment: You're quite welcome. Padding is a weird beastie, especially pre-IE9. Always check those when you have sudden shifts in floated items. Good luck with the rest of the site!